# java.lang.NullPointerException occur upon execution

Tags: netbeans, nullpointerexception, null, xampp, panel

Null pointer exception occurs when you reference a null object, doesn't it? I intend to create an app that manages a store's data such as purchase (stock purchase), stock list, sales, and customer info. The data is intended to be displayed on the app table as soon as the file dynamicmenu1 is run, without clicking any button, but it only displays hard-coded data instead.

[app interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz6tk.jpg)
[Data to be displayed from table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyMeF.jpg)

```
at view.dynamicmenu1.simpannotaActionPerformed(dynamicmenu1.java:984)
at view.dynamicmenu1.access$1000(dynamicmenu1.java:37)
at view.dynamicmenu1$11.actionPerformed(dynamicmenu1.java:404)
```

private void simpannotaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    tabmodel.addRow(data);      // line 984 

    try {
        /** con = (Connection) Model.koneksidatabase();
         java.sql.PreparedStatement prepstmnt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
         */
        Statement stmnt = con.createStatement();

        String sql = "Insert into tb_pembelian VALUES ('" + textid.getText()+"','"
                +textnamabrg.getText()+"','"+textqty.getText()
                +"','"+texthrg.getText()+"','"+texttgl.getText()+"','"+textsupplier.getText();

        //cek stmnt di 'Model.java' di bagian ArrayList barang().
        //Mengapa selalu Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
          //at view.dynamicmenu1.simpannotaActionPerformed(dynamicmenu1.java:960)
          //at view.dynamicmenu1.access$900(dynamicmenu1.java:21)
          //at view.dynamicmenu1$10.actionPerformed(dynamicmenu1.java:378)??????
          //NullPointerException??????
        stmnt.executeUpdate(sql);
        stmnt.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data telah disimpan");
        kosongkanform();
    } catch ( HeadlessException| SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }

    textid.setText("");
    textnamabrg.setText("");
    textqty.setText("");
    texthrg.setText("");
    texttgl.setText("");
    textsupplier.setText("");
}
```

// line 37
public class dynamicmenu1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
String id_barang;
String nama_barang;
String kuantitas;
String harga_satuan;
String tanggal_beli;
DefaultTableModel tabmodel;
Connection con =null;
Statement stmnt=null;
PreparedStatement prepstmnt;
ResultSet res = null;
String sql = null;
```

the 3rd null pointer exception error

```
    simpannota.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            simpannotaActionPerformed(evt);   // Line 404
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Null pointer errors happen when there isn't anything present.
Have you checked your constructor for proper init for your variables.